# How to format SQL query output using case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My output is given below

```
WFH_ID FromTime1 ToTime1 FromTime2 ToTime2 FromTime3 ToTime3 FromTime4 FromTime4
  1     NULL      NULL     NULL      NULL    NULL     NULL      NULL     NULL
  1     NULL      NULL     NULL      NULL    NULL     NULL    11:45 AM  12:30 PM
  1     NULL      NULL     NULL      NULL  10:45 AM  11:30 AM   NULL     NULL
  1     NULL      NULL    9:45 AM  10:30 AM  NULL     NULL      NULL     NULL
  1    8:30 AM   9:30 AM   NULL      NULL    NULL     NULL      NULL     NULL
  2     NULL      NULL     NULL      NULL    NULL     NULL      NULL     NULL
  2     NULL      NULL     NULL      NULL    NULL     NULL    12:00 AM  12:45 PM
  2     NULL      NULL     NULL      NULL  10:45 AM  11:30 AM   NULL     NULL
  2     NULL      NULL    9:45 AM  10:30 AM  NULL     NULL      NULL     NULL
  2    8:15 AM   9:30 AM   NULL      NULL    NULL     NULL      NULL     NULL
```

I need output format like given below,

```
WFH_ID FromTime1 ToTime1 FromTime2 ToTime2 FromTime3 ToTime3 FromTime4 FromTime4
  1     8:30 AM  9:30 AM  9:45 AM  10:30 AM 10:45 AM  11:30 AM 11:45 AM  12:30 PM
  2     8:15 AM  9:30 AM  9:45 AM  10:30 AM 10:45 AM  11:30 AM 12:00 AM  12:30 PM
```

I have tried with the below query

```
SELECT WFH_Id
            , 
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=4 AND Row_NO=1
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_1,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=4 AND Row_NO=1
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_1,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=4 AND Row_NO=2
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_2,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=4 AND Row_NO=2
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_2,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=4 AND Row_NO=3
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_3,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=4 AND Row_NO=3
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_3,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=4 AND Row_NO=4
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_4,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=4 AND Row_NO=4
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_4
    FROM #tempMorning 
   UNION
   SELECT WFH_Id
            , 
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=3 AND Row_NO=1
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_1,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=3 AND Row_NO=1
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_1,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=3 AND Row_NO=2
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_2,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=3 AND Row_NO=2
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_2,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=3 AND Row_NO=3
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_3,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=3 AND Row_NO=3
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_3,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=3 AND Row_NO=4
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_4,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=3 AND Row_NO=4
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_4
    FROM #tempMorning 
    UNION
   SELECT WFH_Id
            , 
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=2 AND Row_NO=1
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_1,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=2 AND Row_NO=1
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_1,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=2 AND Row_NO=2
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_2,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=2 AND Row_NO=2
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_2,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=2 AND Row_NO=3
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_3,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=2 AND Row_NO=3
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_3,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=2 AND Row_NO=4
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_4,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=2 AND Row_NO=4
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_4
    FROM #tempMorning 
    UNION
   SELECT WFH_Id
            , 
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=1 AND Row_NO=1
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_1,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=1 AND Row_NO=1
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_1,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=1 AND Row_NO=2
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_2,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=1 AND Row_NO=2
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_2,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=1 AND Row_NO=3
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_3,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=1 AND Row_NO=3
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_3,

            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=1 AND Row_NO=4
                THEN FromTime
            END AS FromTime_4,
            CASE
            WHEN Slot_Count=1 AND Row_NO=4
                THEN ToTime
            END AS ToTime_4
    FROM #tempMorning
```

I have used case expression with multiple union statement in the above query for getting output.  How to format correct output using SQL Server?

Can anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: Please provide the sample data (ideally DDL+DML) that produces these results. Is the pattern shown guaranteed? i.e. each row will be the next timeslows?

Comment: Why not `SELECT WFH_ID, MAX(FromTime1) AS FromTime1, ... FROM ... GROUP BY WFH_ID`?

Comment: Please don't add a load of meaningless dots at the bottom of your question. Keep all content useful.

Comment: I can't send my question. That is why i put dot. gets validation error from stack over flow(Validation is the questions contains lots of code)

Comment: I have given max. issue solved

Comment: From your answer, getting error => Column '@TimeMorning.FromTime_1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I have re-written the query => select WFH_Id ,MAX(FromTime_1) AS FromTime_1,
 MAX(ToTime_1) AS ToTime_1,
 MAX(FromTime_2) AS FromTime_2,
 MAX(ToTime_2) AS ToTime_2,
 MAX(FromTime_3) AS FromTime_3,
 MAX(ToTime_3) AS ToTime_3,
 MAX(FromTime_4) AS FromTime_4,
 MAX(ToTime_4) AS ToTime_4
  from @TimeMorning
 group by WFH_Id

Comment: It Worked fine..

Comment: @Zhorov Could you or Noufal please make an answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the posted sample data, a simple `GROUP BY` is a possible option:

```
SELECT 
   WFH_ID, 
   MAX(FromTime1) AS FromTime1,
   MAX(ToTime1) AS ToTime1, 
   MAX(FromTime2) AS FromTime2,
   MAX(ToTime2) AS ToTime2, 
   MAX(FromTime3) AS FromTime3,
   MAX(ToTime3) AS ToTime3, 
   MAX(FromTime4) AS FromTime4,
   MAX(ToTime4) AS ToTime4
FROM (VALUES
  (1, NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL),
  (1, NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    '11:45', '12:30'),
  (1, NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    '10:45', '11:30', NULL,    NULL),
  (1, NULL,    NULL,    '09:45', '10:30', NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL),
  (1, '08:30', '09:30', NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL),
  (2, NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL),
  (2, NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    '12:00', '12:45'),
  (2, NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    '10:45', '11:30', NULL,    NULL),
  (2, NULL,    NULL,    '09:45', '10:30', NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL),
  (2, '08:15', '09:30', NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL,    NULL)
) t (WFH_ID, FromTime1, ToTime1, FromTime2, ToTime2, FromTime3, ToTime3, FromTime4, ToTime4)
GROUP BY WFH_ID
```

Result:

```
WFH_ID FromTime1 ToTime1 FromTime2 ToTime2 FromTime3 ToTime3 FromTime4 ToTime4
1      08:30     09:30   09:45     10:30   10:45     11:30   11:45     12:30
2      08:15     09:30   09:45     10:30   10:45     11:30   12:00     12:45
```